# Handling Azure Event Hub events via Azure Functions vs .NET Console App using Azure.Messaging.EventHub SDK, any practical differences?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-eventhub

My app needs a background service that constantly receives and handles events streamed from an Azure Event Hub.

I see that Azure Functions has built-in triggers for this, but the problem is that my app is written in .NET 5 and Azure Function support for it is fairly immature at this point.

I also see from [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send) that .NET has an readily-made SDK `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs`. My understanding is that this will run as a console app.

I'm already using the Azure App Service (Linux plan) to host the main web app.

So if I create a console app using `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs`, I'd want to deploy it as something like a web job, but the Linux app service plan doesn't support it. I guess I can deploy the console app it to a separate Windows App Service plan.

What's the next best option? Are there any practical differences compared to using Azure Functions?

There's also this .NET Core Worker Service that's more optimized for background services. I wonder if there's a place for it in this use case.

These options are confusing me a bit. Your advices would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Azure function` should be the best choice. It has the built-in eventhub trigger and process logic, and easy to setup / configure(like logging via Application Insights) / less code to write. And recently(Mar 10 2021), [it is supported for running production .NET 5 apps on Azure Functions](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/net-on-azure-functions-roadmap/ba-p/2197916). I suggest you can give it a try and use it if no issues.

For `azure webjobs`, in this case, if you're directly using the SDK, you need to write many codes and configure something like logging.

For `.NET Core Worker Service`, it can also be published as azure webjobs if you want to use it. You can follow [this doc](https://elanderson.net/2019/10/publish-a-net-core-worker-service-to-azure/) on how to publish worker service as azure webjob.

Comment: I know that Azure Functions supports .NET 5 now via isolated process, but everything from creation to deployment have to be done via command line manually, especially debugging (manual attachment), which is a pain.

Comment: So the examples I've seen using the `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs` are just a few lines of codes too: Create a consumer group, a storage client, a host processor, register the event handler, and start the processor. When you mentioned "many codes", are there a lot more than this? I mean I'll be using .NET's DI container anyway and re-use my existing service and data layer codes for the actual business logic and logging etc, does it matter if it's done in a function or a console app?

Comment: @thankyoussd, sorry for the words "many codes", I should use "a few more codes". What I want to say is that azure function has already integrated these logics, so you just need to write a few lines of codes than using the sdk directly.  For your last question, it doesn't matter if it's done in a function or a console app:).